# How to display date from a specific month in Excel Pivot Chart

Tags: pivot-chart

I want my chart showing period from **FEB-2020 to DEC-2021**. However, if i filter away January, it will remove January for 2020 & 2021. This is because, "Years" & "Date" They are independent filters. How to only filter away JAN-2020 only?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out.
If create using pivot chart, we can either show month with no data or show month only data. However, show month with no data, u will show full year-month for 2020 which is unwanted.
For pivot chart, u have only 1 way to control month to display is to create dummy data for that month. Then, run a macro to delete "(blank)" legend.
Hit me up, if anyone interested to know more.☺